# lmList plotting error: Object 'cF' not found

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to produce boxplots for different levels of a factor by using lmList() from the nlme package. While it does work for the example from the help page, my data returns the following error:

```
 library(nlme)
 ##dataframe used (simplified):
   **data.1**
   IDf x.var.1   y.var.1
1    1       1  1.856491
2    1       2  2.999224
3    1       3  3.943896
4    1       4  4.903249
5    1       5  6.034319
6    2       6  6.986847
7    2       7  8.024806
8    2       8  9.139255
9    2       9  9.986437
10   2      10 10.760508

##creating the lmlist file fm1
fm2 <- lmList(y.var.1 ~ x.var.1 | IDf, data.1, na.action = na.exclude) 

##plotting fm2
Call:
    Model: y.var.1 ~ x.var.1 | IDf 
       Data: data.1 
Coefficients:
(Intercept)   x.var.1
1   0.8695317 1.0259681
2   1.3724091 0.9508952

Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 6 residual
Residual standard error: 0.1042786

##plotting boxplots ##(or any kinds of plots really)
> plot(fm2, IDf ~ resid(.))

##returning error:
Error in plot.lmList(fm2, IDf ~ resid(.)) : object 'cF' not found
```

Now I have searched and searched but I can´t seem to figure out what this object ´cF´ is supposed to mean, any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
##EDIT:
> dput(data.1)
structure(list(IDf = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), x.var.1 = 1:10, 
y.var.1 = c(1.85649137285461, 2.99922390104585, 3.94389558063648, 
4.90324945760581, 6.03431888678115, 6.98684730318977, 8.0248061251629, 
9.13925481513909, 9.98643662828079, 10.7605079666861)), .Names = c("IDf", 
"x.var.1", "y.var.1"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `dput(data.1)` to make this reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(nlme)
fm2 <- lmList(y.var.1 ~ x.var.1 | IDf, data.1, na.action = na.exclude)
lapply(fm2 ,  function(lmob) plot(lmob$model$x.var.1, lmob$residuals) )
```

The lmList function in nlme::lmList does not return an S4 object, but a more traditional list with numbered entries (corresponding to the numbers in "IDf".

Earlier comments and code that was (a bit) off-target since lmList in nlme is quite different than lme4::lmList:

<strike>I'm taking a guess that the package from which you are using `lmList` is lme4.</strike> I am unable to find a help page for `plot.lmList` in lme4, but I do see that the function exists. I was hoping to find whether there was documented support for the form: plot(lmList-object, formula). Using showMethods I see that there should be such support.

```
showMethods("plot")
#-------
Function: plot (package graphics)
...snipped
x="lmList.confint", y="ANY"
x="lmList", y="formula"
    (inherited from: x="ANY", y="ANY")
...snipped...
```

I was not sure how likely it was that a function call to `resid` would work on the RHS, or how likely it was that a grouping parameter would work on the LHS. I was not able to get plot.lmList to work in the end. What I did get to work was this hack:

```
lapply(fm2@.Data, function(lmob) plot(seq_along(lmob$residuals), lmob$residuals) )
```

I also got this to work:

```
 lapply(fm2@.Data, function(lmob) plot(lmob$model$x.var.1, lmob$residuals) )
```

Comment: I can reproduce this problem with `nlme::lmList`, and `?plot.lmList` is documented there too.

Comment: @DWin I was actually using the nlme package (as i wrote in the first sentence) but after I installed the lme4 package and executed your code  it all worked fine! Thank you very very much!

Comment: @DWin On second thought..:) Now that I have tried to use your code on my real data only two boxplots are returned and not as much as there are ID levels.. any idea how that can be? 
Sorry for being a newbie here!

Comment: The structure of objects returned from nlme::lmList is (confusingly) completely different than that of objects from lme4::lmList. Sorry about not seeing the source of the function. If you had library(nlme) in the code I would have gotten it. I will correct my code.

Comment: Well, maybe not completely different,  but one is an ordinary list and the other is an S4 object.